# Manage contact list using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-app, contact-list

I would like to create/read/edit and delete contact lists (similar to Exchange category, where you can group multiple contacts) of Office 365 Outlook using the Microsoft API. I have went through the documentation and attempted to perform the actions above using Microsoft Graft Explorer. It seems like this feature is missing from the API.

Is this feature really not supported by the API? (I managed to create contact lists using the Outlook web interface).

If so, is there any work around? What I want to do is to be able to group contacts together, and I want to have the ability to assign a contact to multiple groups or lists. Contact folders do not let me perform this kind of organization.